# How to read following string in groovy

Tags: groovy

I am after reading following string in groovy and assert values.

```
[Event[attributes={id=c8475082-fa09-4b99-89c5-9b839d8321f6, name=updateDate, eventType=updateDate}; 
value=[eventTime[attributes={}; 
value=[2014-11-07T04:35:01Z]], 
eventAttributes[attributes={}; 
value=[EventAttribute
[attributes={}; 
value=[name[attributes={}; value=[userId]], 
value[attributes={}; 
value=[1626383939]]]]]]]]]
```

I assume above whole string represent as a inner list, So I tried as below

```
assert ["userId"] == MyList.Event.eventAttributes.EventAttribute.value.text()
```

Then it gives following error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.text() is applicable 

    for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: get(int), get(int), set(int, java.lang.Object), set(int, java.lang.Object), getAt(java.util.Collection), getAt(java.lang.String)
```

xml

```
.....
<Event id="c8475082-fa09-4b99-89c5-9b839d8321f6" name="updateDate" eventType="updateDate">
    <eventTime>2014-10-17T04:17:19Z</eventTime>
    <eventAttributes>
      <EventAttribute>
        <name>userId</name>
        <value>1626383939</value>
      </EventAttribute>
    </eventAttributes>
  </Event>

......
```

How should I do this

Comment: what kind of object is `MyList`?  and xmlslurper or something like it?  and does `assert 'userId' == ...value[0].text()` work?

Comment: @cfrick Basically MyList is a `string ` which mentioned above `[Event[attributes={id=c84... `. Basically its a output string that I get after `xmlsluper ` of `records.Event.findAll{ it.'@name'.contains('updateDate') } `. So my intention is to assert value within that string. For `assert 'userId' == ...value[0].text() ` I am getting `null ` value.

Comment: well then please show us the relevant xml.  interpreting this format makes your life alot harder.  right now i'd say, that `value` is not needed and the solution is closer to: `MyList.Event.eventAttributes.EventAttribute.userId.text()` or `...EventAttribute.name.userId`.

Comment: ok i guess it's the same as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26418478/read-xml-using-xmlparser-with-groovy. so my next guess is: `MyList.Event.eventAttributes.EventAttribute[0].value.text()=='342ADC23-DC59'`

Comment: @cfrick, Yes it is. I didn't continue with that as the original question is resolved there. May be I should continue with that question. Sorry about that. I added the `xml ` here as well. Appreciate your response. Still `MyList.Event.eventAttributes.EventAttribute[0].value.text() ` gives me null value

Comment: you have the working version there

Comment: May be the approach that I took here is not appropriate. I was able to get the value with `records.Event.find{ it.'@name'.contains('updateDate') && it.'@eventType'.contains('updateDate')}.eventAttributes.EventAttribute.value.text() ` . Because my intention was to make sure the value `1626383939 ` ONLY appears under that `Event ` in the `xml ` *NOT* under other `Events `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you are interested in the `EventAttribute`:s, that contain the `name='userId` you are better off just searching for it, assert, that it was found and then check the value.  My guess is, that the order of the attributes might be random.

```
def records = new XmlParser().parseText('''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SystemEvents feedtime="04:17:37" feeddate="20141017" version="0.0.0.2">
<Event id="c8475082-fa09-4b99-89c5-9b839d8321f6" name="updateDate" eventType="updateDate">
<eventTime>2014-10-17T04:17:19Z</eventTime>
<eventAttributes>
<EventAttribute>
<name>userId</name>
<value>1626383939</value>
</EventAttribute>
</eventAttributes>
</Event>
</SystemEvents>''')
def events = records.Event.findAll{ it.'@name'.contains('updateDate') }

// find by name=userId
def userIdEA = events.eventAttributes.EventAttribute.find{ it.name.text()=='userId' }
assert userIdEA
assert userIdEA.value.text()=='1626383939'
```

The toString from the XMLParser are (to me) rather unreadable.  You are better off, working with the XML as your mental model to find your paths.

Comment: Really appreciated your comments and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator can apply a method call to each element of an array.

assert ["userId"] == MyList.Event.eventAttributes.EventAttribute.value*.text()

Comment: Thanks for your response . I am getting null `[] ` value for the above though